# How to install gimp-GAP for gimp snap

Tags: snap, gimp

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and I've installed Gimp via Software Manager (so that it became a **snap**, located in `/snap/gimp/252/`). Now I want to install gimp-GAP. I see no other way than to use "gimp-gap-2.6.0.tar.bz2" from https://www.gimp.org/news/2009/06/05/gimp-animation-package-260-released/. However, after unpacking, when running `./configure` it complains:

```
> No package 'gimp-2.0' found
> No package 'gimpui-2.0' found
> No package 'gimpthumb-2.0' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
> installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

Apparently, this gimp-GAP package assumes Gimp has been installed the classical way (not as a snap). 
What should I do?

Edit:
`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` gives the empty result and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (as one string) does not occur anywhere in the top-level files of the gimp-GAP installation files.
Searching for `gimp-2.0` and `gimpui-2.0` and `gimpthumb-2.0` gives these locations:

```
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimp-2.0.so
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimp-2.0.so.0
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimp-2.0.so.0.1000.18
/snap/gimp/252/usr/share/aclocal/gimp-2.0.m4
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpui-2.0.so
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpui-2.0.so.0
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpui-2.0.so.0.1000.18
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpthumb-2.0.so
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpthumb-2.0.so.0
/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/libgimpthumb-2.0.so.0.1000.18
```

Should I set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/` and then again invoke `configure`?

Comment: Good question: indeed the tar contains source code, so is aimed to be installed on a conventional system. It would be interesting to learn how one can install such plugins for a snap, but if this is urgent and you want to proceed, you could remove the snap and install the regular version instead: "sudo apt install gimp".

Comment: @vanadium Thanks! I'll do so if no method is suggested that avoids removing the snap package of Gimp.

Comment: To use a plugin in the snap package of GIMP, you need to compile it `static`.

Comment: In `/snap/gimp/252/usr/lib/` the number 252 is a version of Gimp. Which might change in time.
In case you should use such a path, prefer `/snap/gimp/current/usr/lib/` as `current` already exists there and is a symlink to your actual version of Gimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

1. Remove the gimp snap:
2. sudo apt install gimp
3. sudo apt install gimp-gap

This solution is presented in https://techpiezo.com/linux/install-gimp-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: Sorry, that is not a solution but a workaround. I want to have gimp python and that is not possible with apt.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you can install plugins as user plugins  in the Gimp user profile. Go to `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Plugins`, this lists two folders, the "system" one in the snap package (or `/usr/lib`), and the "user" one in /home (`~/.config/GIMP/2.10 in recent versions,`~/.gimp-2.8` in earlier versions). Just drop you executables in the "user" one.

If you need to recompile your plugin, you need Gimp header files and the best way to get them is to compile your own Gimp, which is [not too complicated](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-GIMP-in-20-04?pid=18025#pid18025), since the Gimp development+install output put the necessary files in places coherent with plugin compilation if you use the same environment settings). However your GAP is for Gimp 2.6 
and Gimp has moved quite a bit since so I don't know how far you can go with this antique thing, especially if you need Gimp header files.

This said, many functions in GAP have equivalent with Python or Scheme scripts.